# CakePHP v2.0 and named params

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am migrating a site to cakephp v2.0. In some point I use a link with greek charactes:

```
contents/library/category:κατηγορία
```

If I pr() or debug() $this->request->named['category'] the output is shown with %CE%88%CE%BD%CF%84%CF%85%CF%80%CE%B1%20%CE%94.

And because it is passed to a find query it returns no data. In v1.3 the characters wasn't escaped. Has something changed? I even tried debug($var,false); but the same happens.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating your URL via the HTMLHelper or accepting them from FormHelper they are automatically escaped now to prevent malicious URL manipulation; non-latin characters are escaped as are all non-(latin)alphanumeric characters. To avoid this set  'escape' to `false` in the options array, like the below example from [the CakePHP 2.0 book:](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html?highlight=html%20helper%20escape)

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", array("alt" => "Brownies")),
    "recipes/view/6",
    array('escape' => false)
);
```